# jQuery+Greasemonkey: All sites affected, not limited to "window.location.href.indexOf"

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to have code ran only on specific set of URLs. For the life of me I can not figure out why every website I click, it runs the code, and not limited to the sites I limit it to.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   test1
// @description test2
// @include     https://*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


$(document).ready(function () 
 {  if(   (!window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com") > -1)  
        && (!window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.google.com") > -1)    
      )   
  {   
    alert("test");
  }
});
```

Comment: !window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com") is always true, or false if it matches. true and false is always > -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Just try declaring all the intended urls in an array :

**JavaScript :**

```
  var urls = [
    "https://www.youtube.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://fiddle.jshell.net",
  ];

  urls.forEach(function(v) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(v) >= 0) {
      alert("test");
    }
  });
```

JSFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/hyj6gmgu/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var domains = [
    'http://stacksnippets.net', // ***
    'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'http://google.com',
    'http://youtube.com'
];
var href = window.location.href;
var isListed = domains.some(function(v){
    // expecting href.indexOf(v) to return 0 on success
    return !href.indexOf(v);
});

console.log(window.location.href, isListed)
```

```
window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com") // is 0 OR -1
```

so

```
!window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com") // is true OR false
```

and

```
true > -1 // is always true
false > -1 // is always true
```

Something like this should get you there.

```
var domains = [
    'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'http://google.com',
    'http://youtube.com'
];
var href = window.location.href;
var isListed = domains.some(function(v){
    return !href.indexOf(v);
});

isListed // true
```

Comment: sorry, but this isn't getting me any closer

Comment: how would I make your last edit run e.g. $( ".target" ).hide();